# JSON GET data using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

What I am trying to do is, get data from my MySQL database using a Javascript/JQuery GET request and place this information within an HTML table to display which shifts do not contain a User ID.

I am struggling to understand how to display the JSON get data on the page and how to place this within a table on the HTML page.

I am using PHP on my localhost server to retrieve the data and I am able to retrieve the information in a JSON string.

The function that does this is here:

```
function marketplaceShifts(){
include ('config.php');

        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM shift 
                WHERE user_id IS NULL";

        $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $return = array();
        foreach ($result as $row){
            $return[]=array('id'=>$row['shift_id'],
                            'User id'=>$row['user_id'],
                            'Date of shift'=>$row['date_shift'],
                            'Start of Shift'=>$row['start_time'],
                            'End of Shift'=>$row['finish_time']);   
        }
        $conn = null;
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($return);
     }
```

This is the function that retrieves the data that I am looking for and works when using Postman to show me the JSON strings with the information I need.

Comment: have a look at `$.getJSON`.

Comment: Or $.ajax if you need more settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery's [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), you can grab JSON data from a URL, and do what you want with it, like rendering it on the page (you can also do it [without the library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215061/how-to-use-native-javascript-write-jquery-getjson-function)). For this method, make sure you [include jQuery in your page](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).

The request can be made that way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('path/to/your/json.php', displayData);
});
```

Then, just create a `displayData()` function to do the work:

```
function displayData(data){
    var table = $('<table></table>'),                 // Create a table element
        row = $('<tr></tr>'),                         // Create a row
        keys = Object.keys(data[0]);                  // Grab the headings
    for(var i=0, l=keys.length; i<l; i++){            // For each of them
        var cell = $('<th></th>').text(keys[i]);          // Create cell, insert text
        row.append(cell);                                 // Append cell to row
    }                                                 // End for
    table.append(row);                                // Append row to table
    for(var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++){            // For each data element
        row = $('<tr></tr>');                            // Create row
        for(var j=0, k=keys.length; j<k; j++){           // For each key
          var cell = $('<td></td>').text(data[i][keys[j]]);// Create cell, insert value
          row.append(cell);                                // Append cell to row
        }                                                // End for
        table.append(row);                               // Append row to table
    }                                                 // End for
    $('body').append(table);                          // Append table to body
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Thank you this helped so much and has made it easier to understand :)